stm32g431 through arduino ide using st link programmer. com port isnt detecting
im trying to programm stm32g431cbu6 with st link v2 programmer for arduino ide. the problem is the com port of stm32 isnt detecting. maybe there is something with a virtual com port. is there some detailed guide for connecting stm32g431 for usage in arduino ide
ive tried to download drivers for vcp. was expecting board to be detected

If you're programming the STM32 with an ST-Link, there is no virtual com port. You're just programming it over JTAG or SWD. The dev-kits like the Nucleo or Disco boards have an embedded ST-Link, which provide a virtual COM port. But it doesn't sound like you are using that.

By "st link v2 programmer", if you means those knock-off st link v2, the firmware does not provide VCP capability and can't be upgraded to v2.1 to have the VCP.
